# Getting version in post-build for Nuget

Tags: c#, nuget

Code:

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release (
    cd $(ProjectDir)
    nuget spec Entities -f
    nuget pack DeusPak.Entities.csproj -Prop Configuration=Release
    nuget push DeusPak.Entities.$(version).nupkg  $(MYGET_API_KEY) -Source     http://www.myget.org/F/lojaali/api/v2/package
)
```

I have just started to play around with NuGet and want to know how to include the version number in my NuGet package.  I am currently hard coding it into the post-build event which is obviously not what I want to keep doing.  Can anybody help?

This is my current post-build event :

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release (
    cd $(ProjectDir)
    nuget spec Dev-f
    nuget pack Dev.csproj -Prop Configuration=Release
    nuget push Dev.1.0.0.0.nupkg  $(MYGET_API_KEY) -Source     http://www.myget.org/F/api/v2/package
)
```

**Update:**

OK, I have managed to build the DLL with the correct auto incremented version number :

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release (
    cd $(ProjectDir)
    nuget spec Dev -f
    nuget pack Dev.csproj -Prop Configuration=Release
    nuget push Dev.$(version).nupkg  $(MYGET_API_KEY) -Source     http://www.myget.org/F/api/v2/package
)
```

But this version does not show on my list of MyGet packages.  How do I get it to show there so it can be downloaded?  Or can this only be done manually by clicking 'Add a package'?

Comment: The commands look OK. There can be a small delay between pushing the pkg and having it available on the MyGet feed. This shouldn't take more than a few minutes though. Also bear in mind that, if you push a prerelease package (e.g. 1.0.0-alpha), you have to use the -IncludePrerelease switch in the NuGet Package Manager Console, or select the IncludePrerelease option in the dropdown when browsing your feed through the VSIX UI dialog. Are you sure the pkg pushes successfully (no logs)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not clear in your question, but *assuming* you want to sync the version of your package with the version of your assembly, you can simply manage the AssemblyVersion attribute in the project's AssemblyInfo.cs file.

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0")]
```

or if you want to use auto-generated build numbers

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.*")]
```

If you want to deviate from the assembly's version, and only specify the package version, you can use the [AssemblyInformationalVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyinformationalversionattribute.aspx) attribute in the AssemblyInfo.cs file.

```
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("1.0.0")]
```

It's also not clear from the question what versioning strategy you use, but I'll *assume* you want to apply [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org) (where the first 3 version numbers are most relevant). In general when auto-creating NuGet packages, I'd recommend you to create a [tokenized nuspec file](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference#Replacement_Tokens) in your csproj directory, so you can more easily manipulate the package metadata. FYI, there's even a NuGet package to assist you with that:

```
Install-Package NuSpec
```

NuGet will look for this nuspec (make sure it's called MyProject.nuspec) when targeting MyProject.csproj.

```
<package>
  <version>$version$</version>
  ...
</package>
```

I also explained this on the [MyGet](http://www.myget.org) blog in this post: http://blog.myget.org/post/2012/04/27/NuGet-version-token-explained.aspx

A post build that calls nuget pack should be good enough then, *assuming* you simply change the assembly version before building.

```
nuget pack MyProject.csproj
```

Comment: Hi, I don't want to manually change the assembly version in my post build every time though, I want to be able to pass the token that automatically picks up the version number.  So this is the line that I want to change but I am not sure of the syntax : nuget push Dev.1.0.0.0.nupkg  $(MYGET_API_KEY) -Source     http://www.myget.org/F/api/v2/package

Comment: Even if I add the version with 3 digits (like your example, "1.0.0"), nuget generates a file ending in `1.0.0.0.nupkg`. Am I missing something perhaps? My assemblyinfo file only has the `AssemblyVersion` and `AssemblyFileVerion` attributes, and both have the same value in them, "1.0.0".

Answer (score 7):

Just extending a bit the solution provided by Carlos J López, i used the AfterBuild script to actually call NuGet and provide the version parameter.

In my case, I also added "cd $(ProjectDir)" to the post build event, which actually happens before the AfterBuild script.

Cheers,

```
    <Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
      <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(TargetPath)">
          <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="AssemblyVersion" />
      </GetAssemblyIdentity>
      <Exec Command="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\nuget pack $(ProjectName).nuspec -Version %(AssemblyVersion.Version)" />
      <Message Text="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\nuget pack $(ProjectName).nuspec -Version %(AssemblyVersion.Version)" Importance="high" />
    </Target>
```

Comment: Are you saying you are doing this AfterBuild target and a PostBuild event? What would be the purpose of that? Couldn't you just exec another command in the AfterBuild?

Answer (score 4):

This is how you can get a $(version) variable in your after build event, which should be as good as post build.

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(TargetPath)">
        <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="AssemblyVersion" />
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
    <Exec Command="echo %(AssemblyVersion.Version)" />
    <Message Text="Released %(AssemblyVersion.Version)" Importance="high" />
</Target>
```

So you would have to modify your .csproj file since VS does not provide an UI for that.