# How to run 'nuget add' as a post-build event in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I have added a command to the AfterBuild section of my project's `.csproj` file which automatically creates a NuGet package if it is a Release configuration. This part, as specified in the code snippet below, is working well.

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <Exec Command="nuget pack $(ProjectFileName) -IncludeReferencedProjects -Prop Configuration=Release"></Exec>
</Target>
```

I would now like to add an additional `nuget add $(NugetFileName) -source c:\NugetLocal` command to copy the NuGet package to my local repository. Unfortunately, the `$(NugetFileName)` macro does not exist. I could use the `$(TargetName)` macro combined with `.nupkg` but the package name includes the assembly version number, for which it doesn't seem there's a handy macro. Is there a way to do this without using MSBuild scripts?

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Studio 2019 has been added the automatic creation of the Nuget Package when building the Project, so you don't have to create it in a post build event.
Adding the package to the local repository it's just a line of code in the .csproj file

```
<Target Name="NugetAdd" AfterTargets="Pack">
    <exec command="nuget add $(OutputPath)$(PackageId).$(PackageVersion).nupkg -source d:\NuGetLocal" />    
</Target>
```

Comment: may be this is obvious, but below worked better for me
`
  <Target Name="NugetAdd" AfterTargets="Pack">
    <exec command="nuget add $(PackageOutputPath)$(PackageId).$(PackageVersion).nupkg -source \\ss03\SUT\NuGet" />
  </Target>
`

Answer (score 3):

There is an [answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15027219/1453643) which shows how to expose the version number in the after build event. Combining that with what you had already, you can execute the `nuget add` command with the version number included:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(TargetPath)">
        <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="AssemblyVersion" />
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
    <Exec Command="nuget pack $(ProjectFileName) -IncludeReferencedProjects -Prop Configuration=Release"></Exec>
    <Exec Command="nuget add $(TargetName).%(AssemblyVersion.Version).nupkg -Source C:\NugetLocal"></Exec>
</Target>
```

Comment: An issue I'm having with this is that `nuget pack` outputs a filename like `MyPackage.1.0.0.nupkg` while `%(AssemblyVersion.Version)` has a value like `1.0.0.0`. I can't seem to figure out how to change the naming convention for the nupkg file.